# How do I perform a resize animation on an Android view?

Tags: android, animation

Android has AnimationUtils that allow us to do all sorts of scale and translate animation. But I could not find anything that lets me do a resize animation. Does anyone know of a good way to perform a resize animation on Android views?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default animation tools in Android do not provide a way to perform resize animations. Your best bet is to have a TimerTask that changes the dimensions of the view on the UI thread at specified time intervals.